# Android - Controls resolve to null

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm writing a decimal time converter for someone, and I am trying to use findViewById to access some of my controls.  So, I assign each of them, and then I assign an onclick listener to a button(btnConvert).  When I assign the listener, the app crashes due to the fact that btnConvert is null.  I have read into this, but I haven't found a working solution yet.  Please refer to my code below

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.alex_justi.dec2time;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
static EditText inDec;
static Button btnConvert;
static TextView outHours;
static TextView outMinutes;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        inDec = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.dec);
        btnConvert = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.convert);
        outHours = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.hours);
        outMinutes = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.minutes);

        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

fragment_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.alex_justi.dec2time.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Decimal Time" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/dec"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/convert"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dec"
    android:text="Convert" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/minutes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hours"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Minutes: "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hours"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/convert"
    android:text="Hours: "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you trying to attach the `listener` after assign the button in `onCreateView` (`Fragment`) or in `onCreate` (`Activity`)? Have you tried to execute `getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()` after `commit'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the listeners in your fragment `onCreateView()` after you've obtained the references with `rootView.findViewById()`.